# Is it better to select variables before regression or performing regression and then performing tests to select the variables?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, t-test, likelihood-ratio

I'm working on a regression model that predicts age of clients. The problem is that there aren't many variables to work with. So my question, is it better to study correlations and contingency tables for variables then selecting the ones to use for regression OR is it better to use all of the variables then see which ones contribute more to the model through t-statistics and likelihood ratios?